# How to use the python-pyodata module in Python

Tags: python, odata

I am having trouble getting my code to retrieve data from an endpoint using pyodata. I created a project in visual studio 2017 and an example url that works on my browser is `http://localhost:51701/Striker.svc/Answers` I get the correct output even testing using the request library, however my code below to prints out an empty list:

```
import requests
import pyodata

SERVICE_URL = 'http://localhost:51701/Striker.svc/'

# Create instance of OData client
client = pyodata.Client(SERVICE_URL, requests.Session())
print(client.schema.entity_sets)
```

I tested other sample urls hosted online and they all print out the entity set so not sure what I'm missing

Answer (score 0):

I maintain the package and we had problems with XML namespaces which we fixed few weeks ago:
https://github.com/SAP/python-pyodata/commit/dd467e6ad58588d8c6edaae6b99967eb8cfe4c7c

I would recommend you to upgrade to the latest version of pyodata. If you still have the problems, you can instruct pyodata to use your namespaces:
https://pyodata.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/initialization.html#dealing-with-errors-during-parsing-metadata

You can the namespace URIs at the begging of $metadata

```
<edmx:Edmx xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx" Version="1.0">
  <edmx:DataServices xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" m:DataServiceVersion="1.0" m:MaxDataServiceVersion="3.0">
     <Schema xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/edm" Namespace="NorthwindModel">
```

The XML fragment above was obtained from the Microsoft's Northwind service which is supported by default and servers here only the demonstration purpose. In your python code, you would write the following:

```
from pyodata.v2.model import Config

namespaces = {
    'edmx': 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx',
    'edm': 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/edm'
}

custom_config = Config(xml_namespaces=namespaces)

northwind = pyodata.Client(SERVICE_URL, requests.Session(), config=custom_config)
```